# Detecting errors after moving SVN-backed files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I know how to move a directory locally in Windows Explorer, so that it gets moved in SVN too after it is commited with TortoiseSVN:
[How do you move a file in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080/how-do-you-move-a-file-in-svn/46100#46100)

Use `right-drag` -> `move`

Now my problem is that one may forget to do that, and move the directory directly:

- on my machine: everything looks fine for TortoiseSVN; all my builds and compiling uses the moved files.
- on the SVN repository: the move has not been done, everything stays as before
- on a fellow developper machine: after updating, the move is not seen, so the builds break.

Question: **how do you check that all directories and files below a parent directory have the same structure locally than in SVN?**

Comment: +1 for this interesting question. Got the same issue here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First do an Update to be sure you have the latest revision, then right click in the folder that is the root of your local copy and choose "Check for modifications" in the TortoiseSVN menu. You'll see that one file is missing (because it has be moved manually), and one is non-versioned (because it's the moved one in its new location).

Comment: Though during the update, it's likely to revive the "deleted" original folder.