# svn repository malformed: how to fix repair repository structure

Tags: svn, repository, directory-structure

OK. The repository structure has directories "src" "aux" and "script". No "trunk", no "tags", no "branches". Is there any way I can get this code into a correctly-structure repository while preserving the revision history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You should use svn mv.

```
mkdir trunk
mkdir branches
mkdir tags
svn ci
svn mv src trunk/src
svn mv aux trunk/aux
svn mv script trunk/script
```

Comment: That worked, with one small mod: because there was a bit of cruft in the checked-out version (logs, backup files, etc.), I had to check-out a new copy, and then add the 'trunk' dir to that as above. When I then 'update'd the older checkout, everything under version control went to 'trunk/' and the cruft was left in the original directories (for me to easily sort through).

Answer (score 0):

1. create a `trunk` directory
2. move `src`, `aux` and `script` into the `trunk` directory
3. create empty `tags` and `branches` directories for future use

If you have a working copy that contains `src`, `aux` and `script`, you could do:

```
svn mkdir trunk tags branches
svn mv src aux script trunk
svn commit
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080/how-do-you-move-a-file-in-svn) discussion might help.

in short: `svn mv`