# How do I relocate my Android project in SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I set up an SVN repository for my Android project the wrong way and I would appreciated some help correcting it.

I created a standard SVN repository as follows *(I did not create a root "svn" folder because I only plan to store one project in this repository)*:

```
http://myserver/MyProject
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags
```

When I checked in my project it went into the root folder instead of the /trunk folder. So I had the folders:

```
http://myserver/MyProject
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags
    /MyProject
        /src
        /res
        /...etc
```

I've been working this way for a while, using Eclipse and (I think) the Subversive SVN connectors. I know NOTHING about the svn command line. Now I need to move my project to the trunk folder as I should have done from the beginning. I copied the MyProject folder to the trunk folder by copy/pasting in the SVN Repositories view in Eclipse and renamed the old folder, so now I have:

```
http://myserver/MyProject
    /trunk
        /MyProject
            /src
            /res
            /...etc
    /branches
    /tags
    /MyProject.old
        /src
        /res
        /...etc
```

How do I get my project to start using /trunk/MyProject? Ever since I renamed /MyProject.old to /MyProject Eclipse cannot find the remote files when I sync. I tried changing the repository location from

```
http://myserver/MyProject
```

to

```
http://myserver/MyProject/trunk
```

but Eclipse warns that *"The repository root URL refers to one of the resources configured as a structure node. Do you wish to normalize the URL by cutting it's last segment off?"* If I say Yes I'm back in the same boat and if I say No I get nasty errors when I try to sync.

How do I get my code syncing to the new location? What am I doing wrong? I'd preferably like to keep my revision history and not start over again!

Thanks in advance,

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this thread:

[How do you move a file in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080/how-do-you-move-a-file-in-svn)

I think the best option for you is to put everything back as it was before you copied the folder over. With svn, you have to be careful when you move/copy stuff around, because each folder contains a .svn folder. Inside that folder there are references to the actual repository, so when you modify the underlying file system, you bring the working copy in a very unstable and out of synch state.

If you don't have many local changes, you should probably do a fresh checkout. When you are done with that, you can follow the suggestion in the above thread to use svn commands to move folders/files around.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do if you're not familiar with the SVN command line is just to use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) then open up the Repo Browser: Windows Explorer -> File -> TortoiseSVN -> Repo Browser. Now drag and drop your folders or create new ones just like you would in Windows Explorer.

After you've done this, you'll also need to perform a "switch" on your working directory so it points to the new repository path: right-click -> TortoiseSVN -> switch.