# Modify project structure on subversion to use maven

Tags: svn, maven, directory-structure

I have a project created in Eclipse that has roughly this structure:

- src
- conf
- test
- WebContent

  - WEB-INF

When integrating with maven the structure should be more like this:

- src

  - main

    - java
    - resources
    - webapp

      - WEB-INF
  - test

I can either modify the pom to work on the old structure, but I prefer to have the classic maven structure. Is there anyway to move the files in the new structure in order to keep their history? How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move files/folders in SVN retaining history.  See [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080/how-do-you-move-a-file-in-svn).  If you use subversion client integrated with Eclipse (subclipse or subversive), then you can do this within Eclipse itself, by choosing `Refactor -> Rename../Move..`. and commit the changes.

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked. You can change the whole structure and add maven in a single commit, and all history has been preserved