# How Does SVN Mark A File As A Copy/Move?

Tags: svn

If I do an `svn cp` or `svn mv` I can see in the svn log where it was copied/moved from.

Where does svn store this information?

Certain properties like author/log message can be changed retrospectively. Is it possible to retrospectively add this copy/move information if someone just a normal copy/move by mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you move a file in SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080/how-do-you-move-a-file-in-svn)

Comment: How is it a duplicate? Did you even read the question? I even wrote down the commands to do an svn mv! I am asking where the info is stored!

Comment: I retracted my flag but I think the answer you want is in the answers to that question. I see your point that the question itself may be different enough.

Comment: This: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc

Comment: @bahrep that doesn't appear to answer the question. The files have been committed - hence the mention of svn log. I'm looking for an answer like "it is stored in the property svn:mergeinfo" or "the server determines the info <somehow> before sending the log detail"